# How do I use QProcess in an asynchronous manner *without* causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++, qt, memory, qt5

Warning - I am a near-total noob at C++ and Qt.

I'm working on a fairly simple Qt Quick app. Part of this app needs to execute various shell commands and use their output to do stuff. The most obvious way that I could see to do this was via QProcess, by doing something a bit like this:

```
void MyClass::exec(QString args) {
    QProcess proc;
    QStringList argList;
    argList.append("-c");
    argList.append(args);
    proc.start("bash", argList);
    proc.waitForFinished();
    QByteArray result = proc.readAllStandardOutput();
    QString final = QString::fromUtf8(result);
    m_stdout = final;
    emit stdoutChanged();
}
```

This worked, but had the unfortunate side effect of causing the GUI to freeze while the shell command passed to "args" ran (since the command takes about a second or so to run).

So then I tried to get rid of the waitForFinished() call and switch to using a signal instead. Pretty quickly I figured out that I needed the QProcess object to last *after* `exec()` finishes. I tried making the QProcess a member of the class (declaring it in the .h file), which worked kinda, but had the unfortunate result of only letting me run one shell command at a time. Depending on how the user manipulates the UI, the application may end up trying to run multiple commands at once, and this setup resulted in a race condition where anything that tried to execute while something else was already executing got ignored.

So... I moved the QProcess back into the `exec()` function, but switched to using a `QProcess *` instead so that the object would survive when it went out of scope. (I'm guessing this is where the more experienced users are thinking "No. That's not how you do this.", but I don't know a better way to do this, thus why I'm here.) So now I have this mess:

```
void MyClass::exec(QString args) {
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
    QStringList argList;
    argList.append("-c");
    argList.append(args);
    proc->start("bash", argList);
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(triggerStdout()));
}

void MyClass::triggerStdout() {
    QByteArray result = ((QProcess*)sender())->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString final = QString::fromUtf8(result);
    m_stdout = final;
    emit stdoutChanged();
}
```

Volia! The UI no longer blocks, and multiple commands can run at once. And I also leak an entire QProcess object every single time `exec()` gets called. Tar.

In an attempt to free the QProcess object, I proceeded to try using `delete sender()` at the end of `triggerStdout()` in order to free the memory. Which resulted in the application crashing when `triggerStdout()` gets called.

So now I'm lost. My next thought was to try and call the QProcess object's destructor at the end of `triggerStdout()`, but from what I researched, calling destructors on Qt objects is a Bad Idea (I'm guessing because you usually don't use pointers like this?). I think I'm probably not supposed to use a `QProcess *` to do this, but I don't know what else to do. All the ideas I have at this point have various drawbacks:

- Make a `QList` or something to store the `QProcess`es in, and remove them when they're unneeded. This would be great *if* I could figure out which QProcess emitted the `finished` signal. I mean I guess I could use `processID` to loop through the `QList` and find the right process object to get rid of, but that seems clunky.
- Spin up a new thread and then use the synchronous technique I tried at first. I'm not sure how I won't just end up with the exact same problem as I have now, only now I'll be leaking a `QThread` instead of a `QProcess`, plus multithreading could cause problems in the application itself due to how it's designed.
- Figure out how on earth to manually dispose of the QProcess object once it's unnecessary. This seems like the cleanest route to me, but also seems like something I'm not supposed to do.

Assuming those are my only options, I think the first one is probably the best idea (if it will work at all), but I'm hoping there's some way of doing this that is clean, simple, and doesn't break best practices or established rules.

Comment: I have done your #2 option with a QThread in a Qt program that spawns individual jobs. If no one answers and I have time I will look into creating an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a common problem when you want to delete an object from within a method-call that was called by that very object... you call `delete`, which is fine, but then as soon as your method-call returns, the calling-method starts executing again, only to find that its own `this`-pointer is now a dangling-pointer to freed memory, and boom.  :)

One easy way to avoid that trap is to replace your call to `delete sender()` with a call to [sender()->deleteLater()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater), which (as the method name suggests) won't delete the `QProcess` right now, but rather will add it to a queue of items to be deleted on the next go-around of the Qt event loop (read: after the current slot-method-calls from the `QProcess` have all returned, so it'll be safe to do)

Comment: I *knew* there was some basic feature of Qt I was missing here. Valgrind is now happy with me (except for some random debugging code I left hanging around that I didn't need anymore).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this:

```
connect(proc, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

PS. look up the "new" connect syntax, don't use the obsolete SIGNAL and SLOT macros.

Comment: I actually have to do stuff with the finished QProcess object *after* it finishes, so I do need my own custom function acting as the slot. Also, I'm using Qt 5.15, so "new" syntax is quite possibly *too* new for what I'm doing.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 The "new" syntax was inteoduced with Qt 5, over 10 years ago.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 Also, I suggest checking out the syntax to connect to a lambda. It can simplify your code greatly, removing need for private slots most of the time.

Comment: I actually started out trying to use a lambda (and I do use it elsewhere in the code), but for reasons I don't understand, I couldn't use a lambda or function pointer for connecting to QProcess::finished signal - I just kept getting errors in Qt Creator. Only using the SIGNAL and SLOT macros finally made it work. I think it's probably because QProcess::finished has an argument included, but I don't know for sure.